# Month filter is not working with pagination of Tabulator Data table in Vue JS

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, tabulator

I selected a month from a dropdown menu and clicked on the 'Filter' button. After clicking the button, the data was filtered, and it appeared on page 1. However, when I change the page using pagination, the filtered data from the dropdown selection doesn't appear on other pages. Additionally, whenever I change the page, the server makes API calls since it is using server-side pagination.

Visits.vue component

```
    <template>
      <div class="row g-5 g-xl-8">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
          <div class="card mb-5 mb-xl-8">
            <div class="card-header border-0 pt-5 pe-5">
              <div class="row w-100">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="row" id="filter">
                    <div class="col-md-2 pe-0">
                      <label
                        class="required fw-semobold col-sm-auto col-form-label col-form-label-sm"
                        >Month
                      </label>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="col-md-4 ps-0">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control form-control-solid form-control-sm month"
                        name="month"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <button
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-light-success col-sm-auto mt-4 mt-sm-0 ms-0 ms-sm-4 filterTable"
                      >
                        <i class="bi bi-x-diamond-fill"></i>
                        Filter
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body py-3">
              <div ref="table"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template> 

    <script lang="ts">
    import { getAssetPath } from "@/core/helpers/assets";
    import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
    import { tableInitialize } from "@/core/helpers/tabulator";
    import ApiService from "@/core/services/ApiService";
    import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
    import flatpickr from "flatpickr";
    import monthSelectPlugin from "flatpickr/dist/plugins/monthSelect";
    import moment from "moment";
    import axios from "axios";
    import Swal from "sweetalert2";
    window.luxon = luxon;
    
    export default defineComponent({
      name: "customers-visits",
      components: {},
      data() {
        return {
          tabulator: null,
          areaFilterList: {},
          subRegionFilterList: {},
          regionFilterList: {},
          purposeFilterList: {},
          typeFilterList: {},
          filteredData: [],
        };
      },
      setup() {
    
        return {
          getAssetPath,
        };
      },
      mounted() {
        const router = useRouter();
    
        ApiService.get("customers/visits/fields").then((response) => {
          response.data.areas.forEach((item) => {
            this.areaFilterList[item.id] = item.name;
          });
    
          response.data.sub_regions.forEach((item) => {
            this.subRegionFilterList[item.name] = item.name;
          });
    
          response.data.regions.forEach((item) => {
            this.regionFilterList[item.id] = item.name;
          });
    
          response.data.customer_visit_purposes.forEach((item) => {
            this.purposeFilterList[item.id] = item.name;
          });
    
          response.data.customer_types.forEach((item) => {
            this.typeFilterList[item.id] = item.name;
          });
        });
   
        let fieldLinks = [];
    
        let requiredColumns = {
          dataColumns: [
            {
              title: "Region",
              field: "r.id",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: "list",
                headerFilterParams: regionHeaderFilterParams,
                formatter: region,
                accessorDownload: regionAccessor,
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Sub Region",
              field: "sr.name",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: "list",
                headerFilterParams: subRegionHeaderFilterParams,
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Territory",
              field: "a.id",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: "list",
                headerFilterParams: areaHeaderFilterParams,
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Reporting To",
              field: "rt.name",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: true,
                formatterParams: {
                  value: "reporting_to",
                },
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Emp No",
              field: "e.employee_id",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: true,
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Employee Name",
              field: "e.name",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: "input",
                
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Day",
              field: "cv.visited_at",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: "other-input",
                formatterParams: {
                  value: "day",
                },
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Visited At",
              field: "cv.visited_at",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: "dates",
                formatterParams: {
                  value: "visited_at",
                },
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Cust. Type",
              field: "ct.id",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: "list",
                headerFilterParams: typeHeaderFilterParams,
                
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Code",
              field: "c.code",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: true,
                formatterParams: {
                  value: "c.code",
                },
                
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Customer",
              field: "c.name",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: true,
                formatterParams: {
                  value: "customer",
                },
                
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Address",
              field: "c.address",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: true,
                formatterParams: {
                  value: "address",
                },
                
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Contact Person",
              field: "c.contact_person",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: "other-input",
                formatterParams: {
                  value: "contact_person",
                },
              },
            },
            {
              title: "CNIC",
              field: "c.cnic",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: "other-input",
                formatterParams: {
                  value: "cnic",
                },
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Contact Number",
              field: "c.contact_number",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: true,
                formatterParams: {
                  value: "contact_number",
                },
                
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Email Address",
              field: "c.email_address",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: true,
                formatterParams: {
                  value: "email_address",
                },
                
              },
            },
            { title: "Remarks", field: "remarks" },
            {
              title: "Location",
              field: "location",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: false,
                headerSort: false,
                formatter: location,
                clipboard: false,
                accessorDownload: locationAccessor,
                hozAlign: "center",
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Location Picture",
              field: "location_picture",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: false,
                headerSort: false,
                formatter: picture,
                clipboard: false,
                download: false,
                hozAlign: "center",
              },
            },
            {
              title: "Business Card Picture",
              field: "business_card_picture",
              custom: {
                headerFilter: false,
                headerSort: false,
                formatter: picture,
                clipboard: false,
                download: false,
                hozAlign: "center",
              },
            },
          ],
        };
    
        let filterMonth = flatpickr(document.querySelector("#filter .month"), {
          altInput: true,
          maxDate: "today",
          plugins: [
            new monthSelectPlugin({
              dateFormat: "Y-m",
              altFormat: "Y-m",
            }),
          ],
          static: true,
        });
    
        // fiter data functionality
    
        let filters = [];
    
        const dataProcessed = (data, rows) => {};
    
        document.querySelector("#filter .filterTable").addEventListener("click", () => {
         
          if (filterMonth.selectedDates.length) {
            // console.log('filter Month: ',filterMonth.selectedDates);
            let month = moment(filterMonth.selectedDates[0]).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    
            filters = [{ field: "visited_at", type: "month", value: month }];
    
            const LoadMonthData = async () => {
              let params = {
                filter: filters,
                page: 1,
                size: 50,
              };
    
              await axios.get("customers/visits/list", { params }).then((res) => {
                console.log("res: ", res);
    
                if (res.data && res.data.data.length > 0) {
                  this.filteredData = res.data.data; // Store the filtered data
    
                } else {
                  this.filteredData = []; // Clear the data if no results
    
                  Swal.fire({
                    text: "Data is not available for this month.",
                    icon: "error",
                    iconColor: "#f1416c",
                    buttonsStyling: false,
                    confirmButtonText: "Try again!",
                    heightAuto: false,
                    customClass: {
                      confirmButton: "btn fw-semobold btn-light-danger",
                    },
                    timer: 2500,
                    timerProgressBar: true,
                  });
                }
              });
            };
    
            LoadMonthData();
          }
        });
    
        document.getElementById("resetFilters1").addEventListener("click", () => {
          // Clear the filters and data from the tabulator instance
          if (this.tabulator) {
            this.tabulator.clearFilter();
            this.tabulator.clearData();
            this.tabulator.destroy();
          }
   
          this.tabulator = tableInitialize(
            "customers/visits/list",
            this.$route.name,
            this.$refs.table,
            requiredColumns,
            null,
            fieldLinks,
            null,
            []
          );
        });
        
        this.tabulator = tableInitialize(
          "customers/visits/list",
          this.$route.name,
          this.$refs.table,
          requiredColumns,
          { dataProcessed },
          null,
          fieldLinks,
          null,
          filters
        );
      },
      methods: {
        // Create a method to update the table data
        updateTableData(newData) {
          if (this.tabulator) {
            this.tabulator.clearData();
            this.tabulator.setData(newData);
          }
        },
      },
      watch: {
        filteredData: {
          handler(newData) {
            this.updateTableData(this.filteredData); 
          },
          immediate: true, 
        },
      },
    });
    </script>
     
 Global Tabulator.ts file.
    import {TabulatorFull as Tabulator} from "tabulator-tables";
    import flatpickr from "flatpickr";
    import * as luxon from "luxon";
    import * as XLSX from "xlsx";
    import ApiService from "@/core/services/ApiService";
    
    window.luxon = luxon;
    window.XLSX = XLSX;
    
    Tabulator.extendModule("filter", "filters", {
        "date": function(headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams) {
          return rowVal === headerValue ? true : false;
        },
        "dates": function(headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams) {
          return rowVal === headerValue ? true : false;
        },
        "time": function(headerValue, rowValue, rowData, filterParams) {
          return rowVal === headerValue ? true : false;
        }
    });
    
    function getFileName(name) {
        return name.replace(/-/g, "_").replace(/ /g, "_") + "_" + luxon.DateTime.now().toFormat("dd_mm_yyyy_HH_mm_ss") + ".xlsx";
    };
    
    let tabulator  : any;
    export const tableInitialize = (resource, routeName, table, requiredColumns, requiredEventBindings, initialFilters, fieldLinks, tableLayout,filter = []) => {
      let options;
    
      if (requiredColumns) {
        let headerMenu = function() {
          var menu = [];
          var columns = this.getColumns();
    
          for (let column of columns) {
            if (column.getDefinition().headerSort) {
              let icon = document.createElement("i");
              icon.classList.add("fas");
              icon.classList.add(column.isVisible() ? "fa-check-square" : "fa-square");
    
              let label = document.createElement("span");
              let title = document.createElement("span");
    
              title.textContent = " " + column.getDefinition().title;
    
              label.appendChild(icon);
              label.appendChild(title);
    
              menu.push({
                label:label,
                action:function(e) {
                  e.stopPropagation();
    
                  column.toggle();
    
                  column.getDefinition().visible = !column.getDefinition().visible;
    
                  if (column.isVisible()) {
                    icon.classList.remove("fa-square");
                    icon.classList.add("fa-check-square");
                  }
                  else {
                    icon.classList.remove("fa-check-square");
                    icon.classList.add("fa-square");
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          }
    
          return menu;
        };
    
        let datePicker = (cell, onRendered, success, cancel, headerFilterParams) => {
          var filter = document.createElement("input");
          filter.value = cell.getValue();
    
          var datepicker = flatpickr(filter, {
            dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
            onClose: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
              success(dateStr);
            },
          });
    
          onRendered(() => {
            filter.focus();
          });
    
          return filter;
        };
    
        let datePickerRange = (cell, onRendered, success, cancel, headerFilterParams) => {
          var filter = document.createElement("input");
          filter.value = cell.getValue();
    
          var datepickerrange = flatpickr(filter, {
            dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
            mode: "range",
            onClose: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
              success(dateStr);
            },
          });
    
          onRendered(() => {
            filter.focus();
          });
    
          return filter;
        };
    
        let timePicker = (cell, onRendered, success, cancel, headerFilterParams) => {
          var filter = document.createElement("input");
          filter.value = cell.getValue();
    
          var datepicker = flatpickr(filter, {
            enableTime: true,
            noCalendar: true,
            dateFormat: "H:i",
            time_24hr: true,
            onClose: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
              success(dateStr);
            },
          });
    
          onRendered(() => {
            filter.focus();
          });
    
          return filter;
        };
    
        let dateTime = function(cell, formatterParams) {
          return cell.getData()[formatterParams["value"]];
        }
    
        let dateTimeAccessor = function(value, data, type, params, column) {
          return data[params["value"]];
        }
    
        let columnValue = function(cell, formatterParams) {
          return cell.getData()[formatterParams['value']];
        }
    
        let columns = [];
    
        if (requiredColumns.select) {
          let column = {title: "Select", formatter: "rowSelection", titleFormatter:"rowSelection", cellClick: function(e, cell) {cell.getRow().toggleSelect();}, clipboard: false, download: false, headerSort: false, frozen: true, resizable: false, vertAlign: "middle", cssClass: "checkbox-column", minWidth: 40};
    
          columns.push(column);
        }
    
        if (requiredColumns.serialNumber) {
          let serialNumber = function(cell) {
            var page = cell.getTable().getPage();
            var pageSize = cell.getTable().getPageSize();
            var cellRowPosition = cell.getRow().getPosition();
    
            return (((page - 1) * pageSize) + cellRowPosition);
          }
    
          let column = {title: "S. No.", formatter: serialNumber, download: false, headerSort: false, resizable: false, vertAlign: "middle", minWidth: 60};
    
          columns.push(column);
        }
    
        if (requiredColumns.dataColumns !== undefined) {
          requiredColumns.dataColumns.forEach(item => {
            let column = {title: item.title, field: item.field, headerFilterLiveFilter: false, headerMenu: headerMenu, headerSortTristate: true, resizable: false, vertAlign: "middle"};
    
            if (item.custom !== undefined) {
              if (item.custom.headerFilter == "date") {
                column = {...column,
                  ...{
                    headerFilter: datePicker, headerFilterFunc: "date",
                    formatter: dateTime,
                    formatterParams: item.custom.formatterParams,
                    accessorDownload: dateTimeAccessor,
                    accessorDownloadParams: item.custom.formatterParams
                  }
                };
              }
              else if (item.custom.headerFilter == "dates") {
                column = {...column,
                  ...{
                    headerFilter: datePickerRange, headerFilterFunc: "dates",
                    formatter: dateTime,
                    formatterParams: item.custom.formatterParams,
                    accessorDownload: dateTimeAccessor,
                    accessorDownloadParams: item.custom.formatterParams
                  }
                };
              }
              else if (item.custom.headerFilter == "time") {
                column = {...column,
                  ...{
                    headerFilter: timePicker, headerFilterFunc: "time",
                    formatter: dateTime,
                    formatterParams: item.custom.formatterParams,
                    accessorDownload: dateTimeAccessor,
                    accessorDownloadParams: item.custom.formatterParams
                  }
                };
              }
              else if (item.custom.headerFilter == "image") {
                column = {...column,
                  ...{
                    formatter: item.custom.formatter,
                    clipboard: false,
                    download: false,
                    headerMenu: false,
                    headerSort: false,
                    headerSortTristate: false,
                    resizable: false,
                  }
                };
              }
              else if (item.custom.headerFilter == "other-input") {
                column = {...column,
                  ...{
                    headerFilter: "input",
                    formatter: columnValue,
                    formatterParams: item.custom.formatterParams,
                  }
                };
              }
              else {
                column = {...column, ...item.custom};
              }
            }
            else {
              column = {...column, ...{headerFilter: "input"}};
            }
    
            if (column.headerSort === undefined) {
              column.headerSort = true;
            }
    
            if (item.visible === undefined) {
              item.visible = true;
            }
    
            column = {...column, ...{headerSort: column.headerSort, visible: item.visible}};
    
            columns.push(column);
          });
        }
    
        if (requiredColumns.action) {
          let column = {title: "Actions", formatter: requiredColumns.action, clipboard: false, download: false, headerSort: false, frozen: true, resizable: false, hozAlign: "center", minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 100};
    
          columns.push(column);
        }
    
        options = {
          ajaxURL: ApiService.vueInstance.axios.defaults.baseURL + "/" + resource,
          clipboard: "copy",
          clipboardCopyStyled: false,
          columns: columns,
          dataReceiveParams: {
            "last_row": "total",
          },
          filterMode: "remote",
          index: "id",
          layout: tableLayout,
          layoutColumnsOnNewData: true,
          pagination: true,
          paginationCounter: "rows",
          paginationMode: "remote",
          paginationSize: 50,
          paginationSizeSelector: [10, 50, 100, 500],
          ajaxParams: function(){
            return {filter: filter};
        },
          sortMode: "remote",
        };
      }
      else {
        options = {
          ajaxURL: ApiService.vueInstance.axios.defaults.baseURL + "/" + resource,
          autoColumns: true,
          autoColumnsDefinitions: function(definitions) {
            definitions.forEach((column) => {
              column.headerSort = false;
            });
    
            return definitions;
          },
          clipboard: "copy",
          clipboardCopyStyled: false,
          filterMode: "remote",
          initialFilter: initialFilters,
          layout: "fitDataStretch",
          layoutColumnsOnNewData: true,
        };
      }
       if(tabulator){
        tabulator = null;
       }
    
       tabulator = new Tabulator(table, options);
    
      for (const property in requiredEventBindings) {
        tabulator.on(property, requiredEventBindings[property]);
      }
    
      if (document.getElementById("resetFilters") !== null) {
        document.getElementById("resetFilters").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          tabulator.clearFilter(true);
        });
      }
    
      if (document.getElementById("excelCurrentDownload") !== null) {
        document.getElementById("excelCurrentDownload").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          tabulator.download("xlsx", getFileName(routeName));
        });
      }
    
      if (document.getElementById("excelAllDownload") !== null) {
        document.getElementById("excelAllDownload").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
          let required = [];
          let header = [];
          let columnAccessorDownloads = {};
    
          tabulator.getColumnDefinitions().forEach(function(column) {
            if (column.download !== false && !(column.visible !== undefined && column.visible === false)) {
                header.push(column.title);
    
                if (column.field in fieldLinks) {
    
                    required.push(fieldLinks[column.field]);
                }
                else {
    
                    required.push(column.field);
                }
    
                if (column.accessorDownload !== undefined) {
                    columnAccessorDownloads[column.field] = column.accessorDownload;
                }
            }
          });
          let params: any;
          if(filter.length > 0){
            params = {filter,all: true};
          }else{
            params = {all: true};
          }
    
          ApiService.query(resource, {params})
            .then(response => {
                let rows = [];
    
                let resp :any;
                if(response.data.length > 0){
                  resp = response.data;
                }else{
                  resp = response.data.data;
                }
    
                resp.forEach(function(row) {
                    let columns = {};
    
                    Object.keys(row).forEach(field => {
                        if (required.includes(field)) {
                            if (field in columnAccessorDownloads) {
                                columns[field] = columnAccessorDownloads[field](row[field]);
                            }
                            else {
                                columns[field] = row[field];
                            }
                        }
                    });
    
                    rows.push(columns);
                });
    
              const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
              const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet([]);
              XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(worksheet, [header]);
              XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(worksheet, rows, {origin: "A2", skipHeader: true});
              XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet);
              XLSX.writeFileXLSX(workbook, getFileName(routeName));
            });
        });
      }
    
      return tabulator;
    };
Basically Tabulator.ts is using in my component this library I am using https://tabulator.info with Vue JS I stucked in my project in Tabulator JS I need help basically backend of this project is on Laravel 9 and Frontend is on Vue JS 3 this library
```